# How to get the ID of the inserted record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm writing a program to manage the Claims our organisation has. For this I have two table Claim and ClaimStatus. The Claim table contains the Claims and the table ClaimStatus contains all the status changes to the claim i.e. 'created', 'send', 'technically closed', etc.

When a claim is created I insert it with

```
DoCmd.RunSql "Insert into Claim (Property1, Property2, Property3) Values (Value1, Value2, Value3)
```

I then use the Claims ID to make an insert in the table ClaimStatus

```
ClaimID = dlast ("ID", "Claim")
DoCmd.RunSql "Insert into ClaimStatus (ClaimID, Property1, Property2, Property3) Values (" & ClaimID & ", Value1, Value2, Value3)
```

This works perfectly when I have the Acces file locally. But when run from a netwerk folder, the Dlast return the second last value. I assume  this Dlast is run before the DoCmd.RunSql has finished.

What is the best way to get the ID of the inserted record? Please note, that this also needs to work when 2 records are created the same second. So letting the program wait is a suboptimal sollution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is data type of `ID` column? If it is `AutoNumber` then use `DMax()` instead of `DLast()`.

Comment: `DMax()` is dangerous in a shared environment. You need to run the insert query in a Workspace/Transaction and select `@@IDENTITY` to get the newly inserted id for this transaction.

Answer (score 1):

dlast() is not consistent and does not work. You have to use dmax().

However, I don't even recommend dmax(), but it will work better then dlast().

So you could use

```
DMAX("ID", "Claim")
```

Above will work, but it could start to break down if you have quite a few users (multi-user). I never had luck with dlast(), and it not even clear how it works or what it does, but you HAVE to use damx(). I would ignore and never use dlast().

So the recommend way to do this? I would use this code:

Dim strSQL       As String

```
strSQL = "Insert into Claim (Property1, Property2, Property3) " & _
         "Values (Value1, Value2, Value3)"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

' now get last row

Dim ClaimID    As Long

ClaimID = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@Identity")(0)
```

So the above is most safe, and will return the last ID you added, even if other users are working at the same time.